# org.java-Websocket server code on a Glassfish server

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish

I have created java-websocket server as shown in below code.

```
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;

public class JavaWebSocketServer1 extends WebSocketServer {
    public JavaWebSocketServer1() throws UnknownHostException {
        super();
    }
        //all overriden methods onmessge onerror ,etc.

}
```

My glassfish-web.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/JavaWebSocketServer</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I am using below given url to access the websocket but its not working

```
ws://IP:8080/JavaWebSocketServer/JavaWebSocketServer1
```

But this websocket is not accessible from the client. I think there's some problem in URL i tried different urls but did'nt work for me. Please help figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using http://java-websocket.org, which cannot run on [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net).

It is intended to run as standalone server. If you want to use WebSocket on Glassfish, please see JSR 356 - Java API for WebSocket, which is part of Java EE 7. This [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm) should be useful.

Comment: it works very well on glassfish, I tried it. But when it comes to how to do session management i switched back to javax.websocekt server.
Everything is working fine for me now. so My client is java-websocekt client and server is javax.websocekt